# In triangle ABC,angle A=90, AK is vertical to BC, IHGK and DEFK are squares inscribe in triangle ABK and triangle CAK. Proof that AH=AE.:

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In triangle $ABC$, $\angle{A} = 90$, $AK$ is vertical to $BC$, $IHGK$ and $DEFK$ are squares inscribe in $\Delta ABK$ and $\Delta CAK$. Prove that $AH=AE$.

I’ve tried proving $\Delta{AHG}$ is identical to $\Delta{AEF}$ and proving $\angle{AHE} = 45$.

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you.

---

Now I can finish the question here:)

Suppose angle HAG=t, angle EAF=90-t

AK=AG+GK=AG+GH=AH*(cos(t)+sin(t))

AK=AF+FK=AF+FE=AE*(cos(90-t)+sin(t))=AE*(sin(t)+cos(t))

So AH*(cos(t)+sin(t))=AE*(cos(t)+sin(t))

=>>AH=AE

It is more beautiful than I thought ^^

[image]

Comment: possibly coordinate geometry may work though lengthy

Comment: That is the brute force method and it does work. Vectors are a little better than coordinates though.

Comment: btw where even is $X$ and $Y$ that you speak of @Iris ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\angle CAK=t$ and $\angle BAK=90-t$

Then
$AK=AG+GK=AG+GH=AH(\sin t +\cos t)$

Can you write a similar equation of $AK$ using $AE$?

> $AK=AF+FK=AF+FG=AE(\cos t +\sin t)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\angle AHG = \angle EAF = \theta (say)$

You can write $AK$ in terms of $AH$ and $AE$. You will see both of them will have common multiplier $\sin \theta + \cos \theta$.